# I can't find a desired ETF on the popular UK brokerage firms - how can I find one that does?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, etf, starting-out-investing, brokerage

If I wanted to put money in a specific ETF, namely ARK invest (ARKK), but it wasn't possible on the top UK brokerage firms - what should I do next?

So I looked on hargreaves lansdown, halifax, and 8 other firms. None of them seem to allow me to buy shares of the ETF ARKK. But I would still like to know where it is possible; how can I find a brokerage firm that does allow me to invest in this ETF? To be clear, I am asking for a method that would let me solve this kind of problem, or examples of such firms. Or am I totally wrong and it is in fact possible from some of the popular ones?

I am a UK resident and national.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an ETF listed on US markets.  UK brokers and dealing platforms - even ones allowing US listed company stocks to be traded - simply will not make US listed ETFs available to UK investors without a KIID document being available, and most US ETFs don't provide them.  More on this at https://www.justetf.com/uk/news/etf/us-domiciled-etfs.html

If you want to research ETFs you can actually buy on most UK platforms, https://www.justetf.com/uk/find-etf.html is the most comprehensive and accurate list I've found.

Otherwise your only alternative maybe to jump through whatever hoops are needed to open a dealing account in the US with a US broker.

Answer (score 0):

IG lists US ETF's and allows UK investors to purchase. They ask for a W-8BEN form to be filled (takes seconds).